# how to use a variable to define a directory flask python3

Tags: python, flask

I have this sample code below, when I try to go to / I get a 404 error, I am trying to use variables as app routes but with no luck

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

index_dir = "/"

app.route(index_dir)
def index():
    return "hello_world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Any idea on how to make python3 variables to directories

Comment: That works for me. You should add up more information such as error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You have skipped the decorator symbol (`@`) before `app.route(index_dir)`. It should be like this to work:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

index_dir = "/"

@app.route(index_dir)
def index():
    return "hello_world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: This is correct, _and_ it has nothing to do with filesystem directories. Paths in URLs have, at most, a coincidental relationship to the filesystem.